# Waking Create 2 from sleep

Tags: irobot-create

With the conversion of the DD control line to BRC on the series 500/600/Create 2 I have not been able to find a reliable way to wake the Create 2 from sleep. The spec suggests not letting it sleep by pulsing they BRC control but that would not fit my Use Case

Anyone successful in waking Create 2 after sleep?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in fooling the Roomba into thinking I have disconnected, which causes it to wake up when I "reconnect".

My project uses the battery out lines from the mini-DIN, if you temporarily break this connection it causes the Roomba to wake when Vout is reconnected.

Comment: HI Pete, Thanks for the info. I had noticed this "turn on" when I plugged a disconnected iRobot USB adapter cable into the Roomba, but unfortunately for my Use Case of a Telepresence Robot I need to use power all the time. BTW, in discussions with the iRobot STEM Program Manager I found out that the part of the spec I was referring to only applies when the Roomba is undocked. Regards, Frank